# simplex-talk: accept: Invalid argument error with simple socket program

Tags: c, sockets

I do not normally write anything in C, so please excuse my complete lack of experience. I am trying out code from my textbook, and it is giving me an error. I have a client and server executable compiled. I run the server ./server and the client ./client localhost. Whenever I run the client, the terminal that contains the server will display the error simplex-talk:accept: Invalid argument. I have read somewhere that it may be that the argument is a "value result argument." I do not know what this means or how it applies to this. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#
#define SERVER_PORT 20169
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 256
int
main()
{
struct sockaddr_in sin;
char buf[MAX_LINE];
socklen_t len;
int s, new_s;
/* build address data structure */
memset((char *)&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
/* setup passive open */
if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: socket");
exit(1);
}
if ((bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: bind");
exit(1);
}
listen(s, MAX_PENDING);
/* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
while(1) {
if ((new_s = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len)) < 0) {
perror("simplex-talk: accept");
exit(1);
}
while (len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0))
fputs(buf, stdout);
close(new_s);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try checking the return value for listen to see if it is giving an error?

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize `len` to `sizeof(sin)`. Otherwise (`man 2 accept`),

> EINVAL Socket is not listening for connections, **or addrlen is invalid** (e.g., is negative).